# FragmentTabHost: How to share equal space for tab

Tags: android, fragment-tab-host

I have implemented FragmentTabHost in my project and it share equal space for tabs. Its working smooth in android 4.0 and grater. But when i run it on 3.0, tabs are not equally shared the space as you can see in below img. [image]

I need to implement like below [image]

Need help to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sue but you can try this to add android:layout_weight="0" attribute into TabWidget or just post your FragmentTabHost layout.xml file

Comment: I have referred from this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html and its creating FragmentTab dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

U need to change the `layout_width` of the FragmentTabHost to **match_parent**.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the layout_weight property and assign same weight for all the tabs. e.g: `android:layout_weight="1"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in onCreate [slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);](https://youtu.be/WSaSNX5QI-E?t=9m4s)
I also linked you to a slidenerd video where he would explain more